# Can I still use OrbitControls?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am wondering if I can still use OrbitControlsin 2020?

This is the warning I get:
As part of the transition to ES6 Modules, the files in 'examples/js' were deprecated in May 2020 (r117) and will be deleted in December 2020 (r124). You can find more information about developing using ES6 Modules in https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation.

But that just says how to install THREE.js. I don't get how that is an answer to whether you can still use OrbitControls or not. (Please note: I am new to THREE.JS or 3D as matter of fact)

So for now I have installed my orbitcontrols like this in my HTML:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's of course okay to use `OrbitControls` in 2020. However, it's recommended to use ES6 modules instead of global scripts. You can find for all examples files a module version in the `examples/jsm` directory. For instance the file for `OrbitControls` looks like so:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js

You can include ES6 modules directly in HTML files like demonstrated by the official examples or by this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3t0oymu2/). For more serious projects, it's actually better to favor a `npm` workflow and use a simple build tool like rollup to generate your final app bundle. Only then you can benefit from features like tree shaking or code minifcation.